# Merging and duplicating two audio outputs

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, gameaudio

I have a Steelseries Arctis 5, which allows two separate inputs to be mixed in a "chatmix", allowing me to use a physical dial to make one output softer, which subsequently makes the other easier to hear. I'd like to take video clips that include Discord and the game I'm playing's audio; however it only accepts one audio output, making me choose between the two. I need a software which clones those two outputs- allowing my chatmix to function, while duplicating an output and merging it with the other for audio recording. I know it's quite a particular issue, but I know someone out there has a solution- hopefully. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what program you use to record, but if it's not OBS I recommend you try that out. I have an arctis pro with the gamedac for chatmix and I can input the game and chat audios into separate 'desktop audio' channels, and it will record them both at the same time. Only caveat is the chatmix knob wont affect the recording what so ever, so it'll record as if it's perfectly in the center at all times. Of course you generally wanna make sure the 'game' device is set as primary and the 'chat' device as primary communications, but if you run into issues, you can usually force it to work properly by telling discord to output on a specific device (in this instance, 'chat') and use the built in windows 10 output options (right click audio in the bottom right, open sound settings, scroll down and open app volume and device preferences) to tell a game to use a specific audio device as well. (in this case, 'game')